# Using other JVM languages with Tomcat servlet container

Tags: java, scala, tomcat, jvm

How can I use other JVM languages (ie. Scala) with Apache Tomcat?

Comment: You may want to elaborate on _what_ you want to do with i.e. Scala in your webapp.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: [Lift](http://www.liftweb.net/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of scala, you should be able to just include scala-library.jar in `/WEB-INF/lib`. This is because scala is compiled to bytecode.

Comment: Another (better) option is to put it in e.g. Tomcat's lib folder, then you don't have to include it with every Scala webapp you deploy.

Comment: @Knut Arne Vedaa: Only as long as all of your apps will be on the same version. If you need to mix scala 2.7 and 2.8, putting the jar in the common lib would be bad.

Comment: @Malvolio: true but 1/8 as expressive ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As sblundy states, there's no special tricks involved here beyond adding the scala library, either to the app server's common classpath or to your applications classpath.

As with most "Java" web servers, Tomcat works with classfiles and bytescode, not with Java source.  classfiles and bytecode are exactly what scalac generates...